# No mouse cursor in Qt EGLFS on Yocto

Tags: qt, mouse, yocto

I am trying to use mouse cursor in Qt5 application.

When I run ./Qt5_CinematicExperience :

```
Failed to move cursor on screen HDMI1: -14
Could not set cursor on screen HDMI1: -6
```

There is no mouse cursor displayed on the screen.
Same results with another Qt5 application.
The click event seems to be working.

I am using Yocto rocko on kernel 4.14.24.

Do you think Qt5 needs a specific library to use mouse?

My mouse is present as input device in /dev/input/.
A cat command on /dev/input/event1 displays a lot of characters when I move the mouse.

Comment: The problem isn't with the input device. It has to do with the cursor - the thing that you see on-screen that represents the position of the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have this line in your QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG:

```
"hwcursor" : false
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the input device at all: it clearly works. It has to do with the cursor - the thing that you see on-screen that represents the position of the mouse. I'd guess that Qt tries to be clever about how it displays the cursor - as Groleo said, very likely the hardware or the drivers doen't support a hardware-accelerated mouse cursor.

You could easily see that the mouse works by implementing the mouse cursor yourself :)